# How do I create an ISO image from a directory structure on CentOS?

Tags: centos, iso

I'm trying to figure out the exact `mkisofs` cmd to create the ISO with the following directory and file structure. I've tried different commands, but when I mount the ISO that is created the directory tree has not been reproduced.

The initial directory tree is:

```
master.iso::
mount -o loop /apps/vmware/master.iso /mnt/vmtest


ls /mnt/vmtest
isolinux ks.cfg upgra32 upgra64 upgrade.sh

ls /mnt/vmtest/isolinux
boot.cat initrd.img isolinux.bin isolinux.cfg vmlinuz
```

I've used different variations of the following `mkisofs` command without success:

```
mkisofs -o '/foo/test.iso' -b 'isolinux.bin' -c 'boot.cat' -no-emul-boot  -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table 'isolinux'
```

How do I make an ISO that captures a directory's exact structure?

Comment: Have you tried the genisoimage package ?

Comment: What *is* generated?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you running the mkisofs command from?  Have you tried specifying absolute paths? e.g.:

```
 mkisofs -o '/foo/test.iso' -b '/mnt/vmtest/isolinux/isolinux.bin' -c '/mnt/vmtest/isolinux/boot.cat' -no-emul-boot  -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table /mnt/vmtest
```